# iPhone photos taken on camera fail to show up in Photos for ten seconds

Tags: iphone, photos, camera

I take photos or screenshots frequently and then want to immediately send them to friends or share on social media.

Recently I have noticed it takes up to ten seconds for photos or screenshots to appear in my "Recents" album. When they first appear in the album they show up at low resolution and I can't select them, and then a few seconds later they show up at high resolution.

I have 150GB free space on a phone with 256GB total storage.

Curiously I noticed if I took a bunch of photos in a row - say, ten in five seconds - those photos showed up immediately.

I do not have iCloud photo sync enabled. I can also reproduce this effect if I have airplane mode turned on, ie. no Internet connection.

Has anyone ever seen this before? Do you know the possible cause?

Comment: Your phone is processing the photos before saving them

Answer (score -1):

If you open *Screenshot.app* the control bar that comes up at the bottom of the screen has a dropdown menu "options". There, you need to uncheck "*Show Floating Thumbnail*", which is the phenomenon you are (partially) observing.

"Partially" because you missed those screenshots showing up in the bottom right screen corner for those 10 seconds, which allows for just grabbing it and disposing of it in whatever way one wishes.

Sorry, no screenshots in this answer. As it turns out, Screenshot.app is screen-bulletproof.

Comment: Sorry - what is Screenshot.app? I don't have that app on my phone.

Comment: Oh, no, sorry, this is an entirely separate phenomenon than the floating window - it also happens when I take photos using the camera.